# Am I correct? Please verify. "Oriental"

Tags: word-meaning

long time no see. [**This story**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/olympic-athletes-eileen-gu-zhu-120104066.html) has been a wild story here in also my country Japan, and I just would like to check a thing for some and a few.

> Oriental Mysogynist.

[image: Screenshot of Twitter with a user "orientalist misogynists"]

I'm not a bit sure about the use of "oriental".

To be straight, does that mean, Asian, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, asian, or of eastern countries, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oriental

Comment: You ask about *oriental*, but your quote says *orientalist*.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @stangdon Yeah, sorry about that. But If we take the Jame's answer, does it make so much difference?

Comment: @Kentaro James' answer is good, but I think it definitely makes a difference.  "An *oriental* misogynist" is a misogynist who is from East Asia.  "An *orientalist* misogynist" is a misogynist in the style of East Asia.  I don't actually think the original poster used the word "orientalist" correctly, and as James points out, it is being used in a very unusual way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oriental has a Eurocentric origin. It was used by Europeans to describe "others" from "the East". It is a dated term. Because of this, it may be used or interpreted to be offensive. You should not use this word.

Frank Wu, a law professor at Howard University, told the NY Times, “The word ‘Oriental’ is not inherently negative. It’s associated with a time period when Asians had a subordinate status. ‘Oriental’ is like the word ‘negro.’ It conjures up an era. For many Asian Americans, it’s not just this term; it’s about much more. It’s about your legitimacy to be here.” ([source](https://djaunter.com/oriental-vs-asian-vs-eastern/))

It is more often applied to Chinese, Korean and Japanese people rather than Arabian, Indian or Malay people.

"Orientalist" seems to be a new meaning to this word. Ir originally mean "A person who studies the orient"  But here it is used analogously to "Racist" as "Someone who is prejudiced against Asians.

Comment: But it was also used in a neutral sense to describe anything inspired by the 'Far East' - _The room was decorated in the Oriental style_ (using Chinese or Japanese motifs).

Answer (score 0):

"The Orient" is a term for 'the East'. Although some claim the word is 'Eurocentric' - that it stems from the fact the area referred to was east of Europe - actually, at the time the expression was coined, 'the Western world' was referred to as "the Occident". To English speakers at the time, saying "Oriental" and "Occidental" was comparable to saying 'eastern' or 'western'.

You asked if it meant "Asian", and at one time that would probably have been correct. Today, that is still the case for some English speakers, but British English speakers tend to use "Asian" exclusively in relation to India, Pakistan, or countries near them. Today, "Oriental" would exclusively refer to *East Asia* - countries such as China, Japan, Mongolia, North Korea, South Korea, and Taiwan. In general speech, "East Asian" would probably be the preferred collective term for these parts of the world.

Today, some do object to the word "Oriental", and it has largely fallen from everyday use by westerners. However, it would be wrong to say "do not use the word", as it is still in acceptable use in many contexts, including by East Asians themselves. Many Chinese restaurants and takeaways have names that contain the word (just Google it!), and of course, the name lives on in the famous luxury train, The Orient Express.

Answer (score 0):

Well in Turkey and especially in academic language, we often use the adjective ''oriental'' to say ''eastern''. For instance, we say ''oriental dance'' which means ''belly dance'' and that is culturally eastern.

Comment: Although interesting that does not seem to help the OP with its use to mean from East Asia, specifically China.

Comment: thank you for the comment. It helps to show the OP a broad perspective on the topic, I hope. I don't like to cut languages into pieces.